# favicon.ico 500 error when fetching robots.txt

Tags: googlebot, robots.txt

I have an error 500 on my `example.com/robots.txt` page.

[image]

Could this cause any SEO / crawling issues? It's just the favicon , but you never know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your browser requests the `/robots.txt` path, it also automatically requests the `/favicon.ico` path to display an image in the url bar.

A crawler almost certainly won't also request `/favicon.ico` when it requests `/robots.txt`, and even if for some reason it did, I would be very surprised if it caused any issues.

You should be fine.